# Should I use italics or quotes to highlight a single word?

Tags: quotation-marks, italics

> He looked as though he had never heard of the word patience.

Should the term patience be in italics or quotation marks?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Depending upon the context of the sentence, and the style guide of the publication in which it appeared, or of the organization which published it, either would be permissible, though I would expect that quotation marks would be the preferred method of most organizations or publications.

Comment: Search, and research.

'Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!'      [Help Center]    [How do I ask a good question?]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth wasting your breath. The user disappeared two hours ago. I'm getting really fed up of new users writing poorly written/formatted questions and then disappearing after less than an hour *and* NEVER coming back.  I'm thinking about writing a proposal in meta concerning this issue. It's like an epidemic pestilence (is epidemic redundant?) on EL&U. Grrr....

Comment: 'Epidemic pestilence' sounds like a 'repeat for emphasis' usage at worst. I'm nicking your 'and the good questions sink in a sludge of banality' for use when I'm in the mood you're in. On the bright side, I've found some really useful stuff (ie that supports the analyses _I_ like) while digging amongst previous questions. Keep up the good fight, but take a break when you feel you're flagging.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're welcome to nick anything of mine. I am greatly flattered.